# vuejs + phaserjs : not interactive on re-mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, phaser-framework

I using vuejs + phaserjs, when template A `mouted()` I call `init()` function, right now everything work fine (canvas rendered with interaction all ok)

```
<script>
import {GameExample} from '@/assets/js/phaser.js' // all the game scene
export default {
  mounted(){
    this.init();
  },
  methods: {
    init(){
        const config = {
            type: Phaser.WEBGL,
            width: $(window).width(),
            height: $(window).height(),
            backgroundColor: '#0C152B',
            parent: 'container',
            scene: [ GameExample ]
        };

        const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

template A and template B can push route to each other, when B route to A, template A will call  `init()` again when `mouted()`, **phaser canvas are rendered, but inside canvas the interaction like `pointerdown` , `pointerout` , `pointerup` , `pointerover` not working anymore**

Updated:

Phaser relevant code is actually the official example code [click here](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/depth%20sorting/isometric%20map.js&v=3.55.2), I only do a little modification for asset path

```
import Vue from "vue";

var directions = {
    west: { offset: 0, x: -2, y: 0, opposite: 'east' },
    northWest: { offset: 32, x: -2, y: -1, opposite: 'southEast' },
    north: { offset: 64, x: 0, y: -2, opposite: 'south' },
    northEast: { offset: 96, x: 2, y: -1, opposite: 'southWest' },
    east: { offset: 128, x: 2, y: 0, opposite: 'west' },
    southEast: { offset: 160, x: 2, y: 1, opposite: 'northWest' },
    south: { offset: 192, x: 0, y: 2, opposite: 'north' },
    southWest: { offset: 224, x: -2, y: 1, opposite: 'northEast' }
};

var anims = {
    idle: {
        startFrame: 0,
        endFrame: 4,
        speed: 0.2
    },
    walk: {
        startFrame: 4,
        endFrame: 12,
        speed: 0.15
    },
    attack: {
        startFrame: 12,
        endFrame: 20,
        speed: 0.11
    },
    die: {
        startFrame: 20,
        endFrame: 28,
        speed: 0.2
    },
    shoot: {
        startFrame: 28,
        endFrame: 32,
        speed: 0.1
    }
};


var skeletons = [];

var tileWidthHalf;
var tileHeightHalf;

var d = 0;

var scene;

// GameObject Skeleton
class Skeleton extends Phaser.GameObjects.Image {
    constructor(scene, x, y, motion, direction, distance) {
        super(scene, x, y, 'skeleton', direction.offset);

        this.startX = x;
        this.startY = y;
        this.distance = distance;

        this.motion = motion;
        this.anim = anims[motion];
        this.direction = directions[direction];
        this.speed = 0.15;
        this.f = this.anim.startFrame;

        this.depth = y + 64;

        scene.time.delayedCall(this.anim.speed * 1000, this.changeFrame, [], this);
    }

    changeFrame ()
    {
        this.f++;

        var delay = this.anim.speed;

        if (this.f === this.anim.endFrame)
        {
            switch (this.motion)
            {
                case 'walk':
                    this.f = this.anim.startFrame;
                    this.frame = this.texture.get(this.direction.offset + this.f);
                    scene.time.delayedCall(delay * 1000, this.changeFrame, [], this);
                    break;

                case 'attack':
                    delay = Math.random() * 2;
                    scene.time.delayedCall(delay * 1000, this.resetAnimation, [], this);
                    break;

                case 'idle':
                    delay = 0.5 + Math.random();
                    scene.time.delayedCall(delay * 1000, this.resetAnimation, [], this);
                    break;

                case 'die':
                    delay = 6 + Math.random() * 6;
                    scene.time.delayedCall(delay * 1000, this.resetAnimation, [], this);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.frame = this.texture.get(this.direction.offset + this.f);

            scene.time.delayedCall(delay * 1000, this.changeFrame, [], this);
        }
    }

    resetAnimation ()
    {
        this.f = this.anim.startFrame;

        this.frame = this.texture.get(this.direction.offset + this.f);

        scene.time.delayedCall(this.anim.speed * 1000, this.changeFrame, [], this);
    }

    update ()
    {
        if (this.motion === 'walk')
        {
            this.x += this.direction.x * this.speed;

            if (this.direction.y !== 0)
            {
                this.y += this.direction.y * this.speed;
                this.depth = this.y + 64;
            }

            //  Walked far enough?
            if (Phaser.Math.Distance.Between(this.startX, this.startY, this.x, this.y) >= this.distance)
            {
                this.direction = directions[this.direction.opposite];
                this.f = this.anim.startFrame;
                this.frame = this.texture.get(this.direction.offset + this.f);
                this.startX = this.x;
                this.startY = this.y;
            }
        }
    }
}

export class GameExample extends Phaser.Scene
{
    constructor ()
    {
        super();
    }

    preload ()
    {

        this.load.json('map', require(`@/assets/tests/iso/isometric-grass-and-water.json`));
        this.load.spritesheet('tiles', require(`@/assets/tests/iso/isometric-grass-and-water.png`), { frameWidth: 64, frameHeight: 64 });
        this.load.spritesheet('skeleton', require(`@/assets/tests/iso/skeleton8.png`), { frameWidth: 128, frameHeight: 128 });
        this.load.image('house', require(`@/assets/tests/iso/rem_0002.png`));
    }

    create ()
    {
        scene = this;

        this.buildMap();
        this.placeHouses();

        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 240, 290, 'walk', 'southEast', 100)));
        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 100, 380, 'walk', 'southEast', 230)));
        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 620, 140, 'walk', 'south', 380)));
        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 460, 180, 'idle', 'south', 0)));

        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 760, 100, 'attack', 'southEast', 0)));
        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 800, 140, 'attack', 'northWest', 0)));

        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 750, 480, 'walk', 'east', 200)));

        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 200, 300, 'die', 'west', 0)));

        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 1180, 340, 'attack', 'northEast', 0)));

        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 1180, 180, 'walk', 'southEast', 160)));

        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 1450, 320, 'walk', 'southWest', 320)));
        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 1500, 340, 'walk', 'southWest', 340)));
        skeletons.push(this.add.existing(new Skeleton(this, 1550, 360, 'walk', 'southWest', 330)));

        this.cameras.main.setSize(1920, 1080);

        this.cameras.main.scrollX = -100;
        this.cameras.main.scrollY = -100;
        var cam = this.cameras.main;
        // var map = this.add.image(0, 0, "map").setOrigin(0, 0);

        this.input.on("wheel",  function(pointer, gameObjects, deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ){
            if (deltaY > 0) {
                var newZoom = cam.zoom -.1;
                if (newZoom > 0.7) {
                    cam.setZoom(newZoom);     
                }
            }
        
            if (deltaY < 0) {
                var newZoom = cam.zoom +.1;
                if (newZoom < 1.5) {
                    cam.setZoom(newZoom);         
                }
            }

            // this.camera.centerOn(pointer.worldX, pointer.worldY);
            // this.camera.pan(pointer.worldX, pointer.worldY, 2000, "Power2");
        
        });
        this.input.on("pointermove", function (p) {
            if (!p.isDown) return;
            // if (p.x <= 800 || p.x >= 1600) return;
            // if (p.y <= 300 || p.x >= 700) return;
            var camScrollX = (p.x - p.prevPosition.x) / cam.zoom;
            var camScrollY = (p.y - p.prevPosition.y) / cam.zoom;
            // console.log(`p.y ${p.y}`);
            // console.log(`camScrollY ${camScrollY}`);
            cam.scrollX -= camScrollX;
            cam.scrollY -= camScrollY;
        });
    }

    update ()
    {
        skeletons.forEach(function (skeleton) {
            skeleton.update();
        });

        return;

        if (d)
        {
            this.cameras.main.scrollX -= 0.5;

            if (this.cameras.main.scrollX <= 0)
            {
                d = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.cameras.main.scrollX += 0.5;

            if (this.cameras.main.scrollX >= 800)
            {
                d = 1;
            }
        }
    }


    buildMap ()
    {
        //  Parse the data out of the map
        const data = scene.cache.json.get('map');

        const tilewidth = data.tilewidth;
        const tileheight = data.tileheight;

        tileWidthHalf = tilewidth / 2;
        tileHeightHalf = tileheight / 2;

        const layer = data.layers[0].data;

        const mapwidth = data.layers[0].width;
        const mapheight = data.layers[0].height;

        const centerX = mapwidth * tileWidthHalf;
        const centerY = 16;

        let i = 0;

        for (let y = 0; y < mapheight; y++)
        {
            for (let x = 0; x < mapwidth; x++)
            {
                const id = layer[i] - 1;

                const tx = (x - y) * tileWidthHalf;
                const ty = (x + y) * tileHeightHalf;

                const tile = scene.add.image(centerX + tx, centerY + ty, 'tiles', id);

                tile.depth = centerY + ty;

                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    placeHouses ()
    {
        const house_1 = scene.add.image(240, 370, 'house');
        house_1.depth = house_1.y + 86;
        house_1.setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });

        house_1.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
            this.setTint(0xff0000);
        });
        house_1.on('pointerout', function (pointer) {
            this.clearTint();
        });
        house_1.on('pointerup', function (pointer) {
            this.clearTint();
            alert("haha");
        });
        house_1.on('pointerover',function(pointer){
            this.setTint(0xff0000);
        })
        house_1.on('pointerout',function(pointer){
            this.clearTint();
        })
        const house_2 = scene.add.image(1300, 290, 'house');
        house_2.depth = house_2.y + 86;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the phaser relevant code? to see if it is a phaser or only a vue issue.

Comment: @winner_joiner Hi, updated my question with phaser relevant code.

Comment: thank you for sharing your code, I looked at it, and I can't see any issues. Since I don't really know vue and in my limited test (with vue3 and vuerouter 4) everything work as it should. I just can say check the browser console, for an error, since that could stop the phaser app.